# F# throttle function call frequency

Tags: f#

I have the following code to throttle the call of `httpRequestStringThrottled` once a second. However, the function is called without any delay. Did I miss anything?

```
let createThrottler (delay: TimeSpan) =
    MailboxProcessor.Start(fun inbox ->
        let rec loop (lastCallTime: DateTime option) =
            async {
                let! (chan: AsyncReplyChannel<_>) = inbox.Receive()
                let sleepTime =
                    match lastCallTime with
                    | None -> 0
                    | Some time -> int((time - DateTime.Now + delay).TotalMilliseconds)
                if sleepTime > 0 then
                    do! Async.Sleep sleepTime
                let lastCallTime = DateTime.Now
                chan.Reply()
                return! loop(Some lastCallTime)
            }
        loop None)

let httpThrottler = createThrottler (TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds 1000.)

let httpRequestStringThrottled url = 
    async { 
        do! httpThrottler.PostAndAsyncReply id
        return! httpRequestStringAsync url
    }

// Test
[0..100] |> Seq.map (fun _ -> 
    let html = httpRequestStringThrottled "..." |> Async.RunSynchronize
    html)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is actually working fine, as far as I can tell, in F# interactive.  You're just missing the calls to actually evaluate the `Async`s you create in your sequence:

```
// Test
[0..100] |> Seq.map (fun _ -> 
    let html = httpRequestStringThrottled "..."
    html)  |> Async.Parallel |> Async.RunSynchronously
```

Your code creates a sequence of 101 `Async` values.  These are created immediately, but they do not evaluate immediately.  They are only evaluated when you call something like `Async.Start` or `Async.RunSynchronously`.  In your case, they will correctly be blocked for up to 1 second based on the time of the previous call, but that block only occurs during the evaluation of the `Async`, so you have to force them to evaluate to see the effect.

To test your code, I wrote a mock version of `httpRequestStringAsync` that prints the time when it's actually invoked.

```
let httpRequestStringAsync url =
   async {
       printfn "Requesting Html @ %A..." DateTime.Now
       do! Async.Sleep(50)
       return "html"
   }
```

Then, when running the modified version of your test above, I get the following output:

```
Requesting Html @ 8/2/2018 11:15:17 AM...
Requesting Html @ 8/2/2018 11:15:18 AM...
Requesting Html @ 8/2/2018 11:15:19 AM...
Requesting Html @ 8/2/2018 11:15:20 AM...
Requesting Html @ 8/2/2018 11:15:21 AM...
```